# why does set-union and friends not take mutable-sets as arguments?

Tags: racket

I tried `(set-union (mutable-set) (mutable-set))` and it returned an error. But I thought the documentation says the input sets just need to be `generic-set`s?

Comment: What's the exact code you tried? What's the exact error message you got?

Comment: As I said, I tried `(set-union (mutable-set) (mutable-set)) ` and got 
`set-union:
expected: (not/c set-mutable?)
given mutable set: (mutable-set)
argument position: 1st`

Comment: Please add this information to the question instead of leaving it in a comment.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation? That would make the question complete.

Comment: I think the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fset..rkt%29._set-union%29%29) are not clear, in principle I don't see why `set-union` can't work with mutable sets, because indeed they're generic sets.

Answer (score 1):

The contract here is not precise, but it's noted [at the beginning of the documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28part._.Hash_.Sets%29) that:

> - All hash sets implement set->stream, set-empty?, set-member?, set-count, subset?, proper-subset?, set-map, set-for-each, set-copy, set-copy-clear, set->list, and set-first.
> - Immutable hash sets in addition implement set-add, set-remove, set-clear, set-union, set-intersect, set-subtract, and set-symmetric-difference.
> - Mutable hash sets in addition implement set-add!, set-remove!, set-clear!, set-union!, set-intersect!, set-subtract!, and set-symmetric-difference!.

I do think that the documentation could be improved, however.

In case you want to see the implementation of sets, [here](https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/1795bcb924c2eb633f2f4022bf80d2080ffd922b/racket/collects/racket/private/set-types.rkt#L742)'s where mutable sets disallow `set-union`.

Note, however, that it's fine to have `(mutable-set)` in non-first position (and this is documented explicitly in the documentation). For example, this works:

```
> (set-union (set) (mutable-set 1 2 3) (mutable-set 4 5 6))
(set 1 5 3 2 6 4)
```